# item or member, is there a rule how to refer to a container's contents?

Tags: python

Let's take a random container in Python (list, dict...), do you say a container has items or do you refer to it as members? Documentation seems to suggest that only sets have members.

Answer (score 2):

"Items" in Python usually are the things that can be retrieved or modified using the `__getitem__()` and `__setitem__()` functions, so lists and dictionaries have items.  Sets in contrast don't implement `__getitem__()` and `__setitem__()`, so the documentation uses one of the usual terms to refer to the members of a set ("element" being the other one).

Answer (score 1):

I'd say *contents* (that is what a container has inside, after all ^_^) to refer to all of them, or *element* to refer a specific one.

I would restraint myself to use *items* to anything different to the `(key,value)` pairs in a dictionary (as returned by `dict.items()`), to avoid possible confusions.

But if you take a look the list constructor, you can read:

> list(iterable) -> new list initialized from iterable's items

so I guess item is ok to refer to what any iterable yields.

Taking a look to http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html we can find references to both *element* and *item* like:

> particular, tuples and lists are compared lexicographically by
> comparing corresponding **elements**. This means that to compare equal,
> every **element** must compare equal (...)
>
> What has happened is that [[]] is a one-**element** list containing an
> empty list, so all three **elements** of [[]] * 3 are (pointers to) this
> single empty list (...)

and

> The pop() method is only supported by the list and array types. The
> optional argument i defaults to -1, so that by default the last **item**
> is removed and returned. (...)
>
> cmp specifies a custom comparison function of two arguments (list
> **items**) which (...)

but in overall count, *element* has 54 appearances and *item* just 46.

Comment: Not sure about _contents_ and I know _elements_ from Perl. But yes, I've also always called a key/value pair in a dict _member_ or _item_ (interchangeably). I'll drop using the term _members_ for dicts since they have `__getitem__()` and `__setitem__()`, something sets lack. Sets have _members_. For all other containers I say _items_.

Answer (score 0):

Python documentation extensively refers to dictionaries and lists as containing 'items'